# Invalid index to scalar variable (python)

Tags: python, image-processing

I am trying to compare the float in each row and column to a user input (0-255). If the input is within the standard deviation of the float; then I set the values to red. (hence the 255,0,0).
I don't understand what this error is 
[iterating through a matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsGnx.png)

```
  user_input = input("Lorum Ipsum : ") 

  avg_img = sum(images) / len(images)
  std_dev = np.std(avg_img, dtype=np.float64)


  for i in range(0, len(avg_img)): #i is row
    for j in range(0, len(avg_img[i])): #j is column
        if (std_dev[i][j] > (user_input)).any() : 
            avg_img[i][j] = [255.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: Please, replace your image with the actual code.

Comment: What is `std_dev`? `user_input`? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](/help/mcve).

Comment: std_dev = standard deviation of the average value per pixel. user_input is the input a user would enter.

Comment: Please show how they are defined, a description in word is not sufficient. Most likely there is a significant difference between what you mean `std_dev` to be, and what it actually is.

Comment: Hope this helps!

Comment: now... what is `images`?

Comment: You are trying to treat a scalar value as a list: `avg_img[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you observe is related to the following piece of code:

```
std_dev[i][j]
```

because `std_dev` is a scalar or single number and does not support indexing.

Possibly, you want to use the `axis` parameter of `np.std()` and perhaps you want to use `images` (or `np.array(images)`) as input to it.

---

Also:

- it may be possible that you would prefer to use `np.mean()` instead of `sum() / len()`. It is hard to say without knowing what `images` is.
- the result of `input()` is a `str`ing and, quite likely, you do not want to compare a number with a string, but instead you want to convert to say `float()` or `int()`.
- please use meaningful names: `user_input` is a poor choice as it describes more where it originates more than it contains. `threshold` is a much better name